# Работа JavaScript'ов в разных браузерах.

Tags: javascript

Доброй ночи! Писал свой сайт с использованием JavaScript и заметил такую фишку, что в Opere 11.60 код напрочь не работает (даже элементарно alert не выводит), хотя в настройках стоит что javascript включен. В IE код javascript работает, но почему-то иногда глючит (удаление записей таблицы множественное иногда не до конца проходит, тоесть не всегда выполняется ajax запрос-post на удаление записей). В FireFox работает тоже код, но при добавлении записи поле input не очищается почему-то после нажатия кнопки "Добавления". Везде разное поведение кода. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 2):

Это связано с различиями в реализации спецификации ECMAScript-262 различными браузерами для своих JavaScript-движков. Все три упомянутых браузера работают на разных JavaScript-движках:

- IE - Chakra
- Opera - Carakan
- Firefox - SpiderMonkey

Comment: И что даже элементарное сообщение alert("Hello Word"); как-то по особенному надо писать в каждом браузере? Не говоря уже о более сложных примерах...

Comment: "Хелоу ворлд" работает везде. Используйте jQuery она по максимуму нивелирует различие браузеров, и код написанный при помощи него работает везде одинаково.

Comment: Ну я просто для пробы проверил написать хелоу ворлд в опере 11.60 и код не выполнялся, хотя в других браузерах работал... Я кстати использую в своем проекте библиотеки jQuery, но это не решило проблему работы в опере... Что самое странное до этого работало, а потом перестало работать.

Comment: >И что даже элементарное сообщение alert("Hello Word"); как-то по особенному надо писать в каждом браузере?

не преувеличивайте? везде одинаково:

1. [IE 10][1]

2. [Firefox 25][2]

3. [Chrome 31][3]



  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/JodioJG.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/IMVerez.png
  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/KayyOQb.png

Comment: У меня в Opere 11.60 не работает хеллоу ворд. Хотя в настройках браузера стоит, что javascript включен. С чем это может быть связано?